# Spark doesn't read the file properly

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, flume

I run Flume to ingest Twitter data into HDFS (in JSON format) and run Spark to read that file.

But somehow, it doesn't return the correct result: it seems the content of the file is not updated.

Here's my Flume configuration:

```
TwitterAgent01.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent01.channels = MemoryChannel01
TwitterAgent01.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.channels = MemoryChannel01
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxx
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxx
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxx
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxx
TwitterAgent01.sources.Twitter.keywords = some_keywords

TwitterAgent01.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemoryChannel01
TwitterAgent01.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent01.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://hadoop01:8020/warehouse/raw/twitter/provider/m=%Y%m/
TwitterAgent01.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent01.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent01.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent01.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent01.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 0
TwitterAgent01.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 86400

TwitterAgent01.channels.MemoryChannel01.type = memory
TwitterAgent01.channels.MemoryChannel01.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent01.channels.MemoryChannel01.transactionCapacity = 10000
```

After that I check the output with `hdfs dfs -cat` and it returns more than 1000 rows, meaning that the data was successfully inserted.

But in Spark that's not the case

```
spark.read.json("/warehouse/raw/twitter/provider").filter("m=201802").show()
```

only has 6 rows.

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of why you specified the latter part of the path as the condition expression of `filter`.

I believe to correctly read your file you can just write:

```
spark.read.json("/warehouse/raw/twitter/provider/m=201802").show()
```

Comment: thanks @stefanobaghino, I've tried that too...but still, spark returns incorrect amount of rows

Comment: @Yusata What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: I use spark 2.2.0, flume 1.7.0, and hadoop 2.7.3

Comment: Can you check how Flume formats your JSON output? You may have to set `spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json(path)` depending on whether Flume outputs an actual JSON with an array of objects or a text file with one object per line, which is what Spark expects by default.